# Devise Invitable : Optionally Send Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

in devise invitable, you can invite a new user by performing:

```
User.invite!(:email => "new_user@example.com", :name => "John Doe")
```

What I would like to do is (sometimes) prevent devise invitable from sending out an email. I found the following code in the library:

```
def invite!
        if new_record? || invited?
          self.skip_confirmation! if self.new_record? && self.respond_to?(:skip_confirmation!)
          generate_invitation_token if self.invitation_token.nil?
          self.invitation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
          save(:validate => false)
          ::Devise.mailer.invitation_instructions(self).deliver
        end
      end
```

Any ideas on how to best update that to not send out the email on the last line? I'm not familiar with the ::

thanks

Comment: You could comment out the last line: `# ::Devise.mailer.invitation_instructions(self).deliver`

Comment: @The, well I want the email sent in some cases but not all cases. Just wondering if there is a param I can pass.

Comment: I was able to overwrite the method to customize it by adding it to my users model. problem is now I get the error "NoMethodError (undefined method `invitation_instructions' for 
Devise::Mailer:Class): 
  app/models/user.rb:139:in `invite!' " Any ideas how I can add this to my users model and not get the errors?

Answer (score 12):

you can use:

```
User.invite!(:email => "new_user@example.com", :name => "John Doe") do |u|
  u.skip_invitation = true
end
```

or

```
User.invite!(:email => "new_user@example.com", :name => "John Doe", :skip_invitation => true)
```

this will skip invitation email.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I've discovered that 'skip_invitation' is not working for instances, only for classes... so @user.invite!() is not respecting :skip_invitation parameter

Comment: you're able to use the skip_invitation attribute on the instance directly by setting it like @user.skip_invitation = true and then calling @user.invite!

Answer (score 0):

In your invitations_controller (there should already be one that inherits from Devise::InvitationsController), you can add the following

```
  # this is called when creating invitation
  # should return an instance of resource class
  def invite_resource
    if new_record? || invited?
      self.skip_confirmation! if self.new_record? && self.respond_to?(:skip_confirmation!)
      super
    end
  end
```

This will override Devise's method for inviting, and then call the original Devise method (super) only if the condition is met. Devise should then handle the token generation and send the invite. You may also want to setup what the app does if the condition is false, in my case that looks like this:

```
  def invite_resource
    if user_params[:is_free] == "true"
      super
    else
      # skip sending emails on invite
      super { |user| user.skip_invitation = true }
    end
  end
```

when `params[:is_free]` is set to `''true''` the invitation is sent, otherwise the resource is created, but no invitation is sent.

After some digging I found this solution here: https://github-wiki-see.page/m/thuy-econsys/rails_app/wiki/customize-DeviseInvitable