# Devise invitable send out email even when u.skip_invitation = true

Tags: devise

Why doesn't this stop the invitation from being sent?

Using 0.6.0

```
@user_obj = User.new(params[:user])
if @user_obj.valid?
  @user_obj.invite! do |u|
    u.skip_confirmation!
    u.skip_invitation = true
  end
end
```

Comment: 0.6.0 is sooooooo old. try to update it.

Comment: devise invitable is at 0.6.1, soooooooo no it's not.

Comment: ah, sorry. I thought you are talking about devise gem version, not devise_invitable.

Comment: dupe/related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4599812/252799

Comment: I had the same problem - it looks like 'skip_invitation' is not working for instances, only for User.invite! ...

Comment: Hector Villareal's comment here resolved this for me when wanting to skip an invitation on an @user instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599812/devise-invitable#comment19216667_5868476